# Function "chaining" with && operator returns undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have these functions:

```
function A1()
{
    return B() && C();
}

function A2()
{
    return
        B() && 
        C();
}

function B()
{
    return true;
}

function C()
{
    return true;
}
```

Calling A1 returns true, but A2 returns undefined. The only difference between A1 and A2 is white space. What is going on? In my real code, I do not want to write my A1 function a as a single line because it will be very long and not very readable.

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745743/automatic-semicolon-insertion-return-statements

Comment: Javascript ASI. Oh joy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are falling victim to [automatic semicolon insertion](http://es5.github.io/#x7.9). The interpreter will add a semicolon after your return statement, so this is effectively what's happening:

```
function A2()
{
    return;
    //    ^ Automatically inserted semicolon
        B() && 
        C();
}
```

Since you now have a `return` statement with no explicit return value, the function will return `undefined`.

If you look at the grammar for `return` statements in the spec:

> *ReturnStatement* `:`
>     `return` [no *LineTerminator* here] *Expression*`;`

You can see that it does not allow line terminators between the `return` keyword and the expression (this is known as a "restricted production"). If a line terminator is encountered, the third rule of automatic semicolon insertion applies:

> When, as the program is parsed from left to right, a token is encountered that is allowed by some production of the grammar, but the production is a restricted production and the token would be the first token for a terminal or nonterminal immediately following the annotation “[no LineTerminator here]” within the restricted production (and therefore such a token is called a restricted token), and the restricted token is separated from the previous token by at least one LineTerminator, then a semicolon is automatically inserted before the restricted token.

---

> I do not want to write my A1 function a as a single line because it will be very long...

You can still break your `return` statement over multiple lines, you just need to be careful about where you put the line breaks (just make sure they occur in the *Expression* rather than before it):

```
function A2()
{
    return B() &&
    //           ^ Invalid to put a semicolon here, so ASI doesn't apply
        C();
}
```

Comment: Great answer - did not know anything about that!

Answer (score 1):

```
return (
    B() && 
    C()
);
```

will work as well