# CS1513 C# } expected Error

Tags: c#

I am really knew to programming so please be nice haha. Excuse the "Noob" Question, I'm just experimenting right now. Can anyone give me tips on what is causing

```
CS1513  C# } expected
```

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string country = "USA";
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, What country are you from?");
            string countryName = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            if (countryName == country) ;
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are Eligable for the competition ! :-) ");
            } 
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("You are not Eligable, Sorry!!");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to give an answer based on the country of the user basically.

Comment: ```if (countryName == country) ;``` => ```if (countryName == country)```

Comment: One of the things everyone does wrong sometimes

Comment: At what line did it tell you this error was occuring? You should always include this information when you have it available!

Comment: The lesson here for the noob is not just "a semicolon is an empty statement".  **You got a warning from the compiler explaining the problem, which you ignored**.  The lesson here is **noobs should read the compiler warnings**. We put them in there for you!

Answer (score 3):

Remove the ; from if (countryName == country) ;

The ; is a statement terminator. See [why do some lines not have semicolon in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26803462/why-do-some-lines-not-have-semicolon-in-c)

Comment: To clarify: the semi is an *empty statement*, which is the consequence portion of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You put a `;` after your `if` statement.

It should be `if (countryName == country)` instead of `if (countryName == country) ;`

Comment: Hahahahahaha, my bad. I Appreciate that man. Noob mistakes heh

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.