# Statement-terminator (;) operator after iteration statement: Ends the iteration statement itself, or an invisible empty statement?

Tags: c#, iteration, semantics

During [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26803505/1253136), our beloved Jon Skeet considers the case that `do {} while ()` requires a statement-terminator because `while()` requires a statement-body, and proceeds to exemplify that:

> `while (true);` (empty statement) or `while (true) {}` (block statement)

...would be valid.

---

Things are quite straightforward with the second example; the while-loop executing the compound (block) statement (`{}`), which is empty.

The first example however, together with Skeet's description, sparked an interesting question to me:

Does the `;` in `while(true);` (or any other iteration statement) terminate the `while` (/statement) itself (in some sense), or does it terminate an actual invisible empty statement between `)` and the terminator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a grammar standpoint, it terminates the statement. That's a pretty odd way to think about it though. `while` loops must have a body, so if you just write

```
while(true)
```

The parser doesn't know where the "statement" ends as its missing a token. You could similarly "terminate" the statement with another statement.

```
while (true) i++;
```

Is just as valid as just the `;`. The way you really should think about it is that writing

```
while (true) ;
```

Is really a while loop with an empty statement as its body, not trying to think of what "terminates the statement"

Comment: Grammar? According to the spec, a while statement consists of the token `while`, a `(`, a `boolean_expression`, a `)`, and an `embedded_statement`. Then the definition of `embedded_statement` includes a lot of different things, including `block` and `empty_statement`. In fact `embedded_statement` can be all kinds of statements except `labeled_statement` and `declaration_statement`, so these are the only "statements" you cannot use there. For example `while (true) var i = 42;` should be illegal (you can use a block, however). In the example `while (true) ;` there is an `empty_statement`.

Answer (score 0):

A use case for this would be if you had `while(something());` it would execute `something()` till it returns false. So you don't necessarily *need* a body.

This would be equivalent to something like

```
while(true){
    if (something()) break;
}
```

You could use this like an `await` operator waiting for an action.

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer you linked to it's definitely of an empty statement.

From [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26803505/939213):

> There's a semi-colon at the end of every expression statement and declaration statement.
>
> (`if`, `for` etc statements aren't expression or declaration statements.)

and `while` seems to be the same (except that `do...while` is an exception as mentioned there).